# RxJava Observable interval on exact time tick

Tags: android, rx-java2

I am trying to execute something with RxJava at the exact second tick, standard approach would be to use Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS) however this will just guarantee that onNext is called every second but not on the exact second tick.

So, an approach could be to use "initialDelay" option in .interval like Observable.interval(System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS) to start at exact second and then hope that all subsequential calls will be correct, but thats a bit risky.

So is there any way to do this natively without having my own Thread outside of the Observable?

Comment: It really depends on the scheduler type and platform. The `Scheduler` API specifies periodic scheduling compensates for time spent in reacting to timer ticks, but just the OS scheduling accuracy could get you +/- 15 milliseconds per ticks. Why do you need to align the execution that precisely?

Comment: I need the execution that precisely because its triggering a clock in Android among other things. +/- 15 milliseconds would be absolutely fine, but if you add 15 milliseconds at every cycle then after 50 secs you will have a 500ms skew which is not fine anymore

Comment: You could run some experiment with `interval` to see how it works in your context, for example, by printing the current time at each tick, using `timeInterval` and printing the difference over time.

Comment: Its an Android app i cant do that and be sure it will work for days without issues on every device, i need to sync every tick, maybe i could just do Thread.sleep(System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000) in a loop but it doesnt look very "rx"

Answer (score 0):

```
Observable.timer(delay, interval, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

Comment: Yes, this is something i am also suggesting in the OP however does that guarantee that check will be done at every single call so there might be a delay when executed for long periods. Also your proposal emits once, i need it to keep running.

Comment: Looks like `timer` is deprecated and `interval` is suggested to be used. I will test them now. What version of RxJava do you use?

Comment: RxJava2 the approach with interval works but doesnt guarantee that after one hour there will be a clock skew for some reason

Comment: This is a big amount of time. In this case, you should use something else, like an alarm, because is precisely

Comment: Not sure you understood, i want an event to be fired exactly every second tick, if i use Observable.interval(System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS) it will do the trick BUT i am not sure if that will still be in sync after one hour, so after firing 3600 events, since it checks the delta only at first run